# How to Change "to-markdown.js" So it Will Run as Server Side JScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic, jscript

I am trying to wrap a javascript in `<script type="javascript" runat="server"> ... </script>` tags so that I can access it from vbScript/classic asp.

Normally this works fine, but I think there is something in the script I am trying to use that isn't compatible with jScript, but I am not sure how to change it so that it just works.

The js I am trying to use is here: https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown/blob/master/dist/to-markdown.js

The error i am seeing in jScript is :

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a01b6'
Object doesn't support this property or method
/bfadmin/markdown/h2m.asp, line 583
```

...line 583 is this line of the source javascript:

```
Object.keys(voidElements).forEach(function (name) {
```

I am not trying to use any of the extenstions... so if those are whats causing the issue, they could be removed. I am just not sure what to remove in order to use it.

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so, how must the js be changed to work as jscript.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is an ECMAScript 5 method, and server-side JScript is generally ECMAScript 3. One way to get around this without modifying the script you're including is by using a polyfill, such as the one from the MDN documentation I linked to. More generally, there are polyfill libraries out there that add mostly-compatible ECMAScript 5 methods to ECMAScript 3 environments.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I can't seem to get that polyfill to work... Is is as simple as copying that code and pasting it above the problem script in the same script block?

Comment: It should be just a copy/paste. It's been a while since I've dealt with polyfills so I really couldn't help much further.